# Firebase functions and twilio

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I want to send an sms using twilio when a data is created in realtime databse

i have created the following code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const accountSid = "id";
const authToken = "code";
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
exports.sendSMSNotfication = functions.database.ref('issue/{id}').onCreate(evt =>{
    client.messages
    .create({
       body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
       from: '+1sender',
       to: '+reciever'
     })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
    
});
```

but when i deploy it the following error pop up

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        sendSMSNotfication(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:sendSMSNotfication"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

the sms sending code is correct as i have tried to send it using normal terminal command and it worked

Comment: What happens if you do `return client.messages.create({
       body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
       from: '+1sender',
       to: '+reciever'
     })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid); return null;);`? I.e. returning the promises chain in order to correctly manage the Cloud Function lifecycle.

Comment: In addition to Renaud's bug fix, also make sure `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin` and `twilio` are all in your dependencies in `package.json`

Comment: @user15520720 did any of these approaches work for you?